# PHP & MySQL - Create a multidimensional array in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I found similar problems to this already answered but any of them was the same of my situation.

I have a loop iterating a mysql data object and I'd like to construct a multidimensional array  based on all the results, but for instance, if I do this:

```
$i=0; 
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($raw_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
     $row2[0] = array('father'+.$i => $children);
     $i++;
}
```

It only keeps the last child (and his father). And if I do this:

```
while($children = mysql_fetch_array($raw_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
     $myData[0] = array('father1' => $children, 'father2' => $children);
}
```

Then it works fine, it keeps both fathers, but obviously this won't work dynamically because each iteration overwrites the last one.

So is there a way to append this data instead of overwrite it?

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
$row2[] = array('father'.$i => $children);
```

or to

```
$row2['father'.$i] = $children;
```

Comment: Yeah, essentially you're just trying to push to the array instead of update it at position 0 every time. That's why it's overwriting. You could also use array_push( $row2, array('father'.$i => $children) );